# Remap/disable modifier keys on international keyboard

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I use a swedish keyboard layout.

[image: image code]

Which means in order to get `~` I have to input `AltGr + ¨` (char to the right of `Å`) twice, or followed by a space.

And to get `^` I have to input `shift + ¨` twice or followed by a space.

This exists so that I can type characters such as õ, ü and â. Which I never need to do.

Also, `shift + 4` is `¤` instead of `$` like on the US keyboard layout.

Is there a way to remap single click `¨` to `~` and `shift + ¨` to `^`? And possibly `shift + 4` to `$`?